# Prove that the two sequences $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ and $(b_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ have the same limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ and $(b_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be two sequences with positive real numbers, which simultaneously meet the conditions:

$$\frac{4}{3}a_{n+1}^{2}\geq a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}+\frac{1}{n}$$  $$\frac{8}{9}b_{n+1}^{3}\geq a_{n}^{3}+b_{n}^{3}+\frac{1}{n}$$

Prove that $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ and $(b_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ have the same limit.

I noticed that $(2a_{n+1})^{2}\geq 3(a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2}+\frac{1}{n})$ and $(2b_{n+1})^{3}\geq 3^{2}(a_{n}^{3}+b_{n}^{3}+\frac{1}{n})$, but I don't know how to approach this type of problem. Transforming the equation into a limit, wouldn't help that much, nor using the quad and cubic formulas. Cauchy's inequality also doesn't help here. Any help would be appreciared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the relation 2 implies $cb_{n+1} > b_n$ with $c^3=8/9$ so $c<1$; iterating one has $b_n<c^mb_{n+m}$ so in particular if $b_n$ has a subsequence $b_{n_k}$ bounded by some $M$ one gets for $n_k >n$ that $b_n < Mc^{n_k-n} \to 0, k \to \infty$ so $b_n= 0$ and that is impossible

Hence $b_n \to \infty$ and then from the first relation we have $a_{n+1} >b_n\sqrt 3/2 $ so $a_n \to \infty$ too and we are done!

Comment: thank you! I thought it was a way harder problem.